# Trying to get my website to fit all resolutions

Tags: html, css, background, styling, screen-resolution

Okay so I am trying to get my website to fit all resolutions or screen sizes because I am currently working on a 17" 1920x1080 screen size and my website looks fine but when i try run it on a 10" or 15" screen etc the website screws up, the content goes everywhere (mainly drops down) So I was wondering how this can be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: try using bootstrap for responsive website.

Comment: Well.. Welcome to StackOverflow! On StackOverlfow your supposed to show us your code.Why? For we don't go in blind trying to answer your question. Please copy and paste relevant code here.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Why would he use bootstrap and he doesn't know the basics of HTML and CSS. You're going to make him/her even more confused.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use percentage values (e.g. `width:20%;` instead of `width:200px;`) whenever you can, so you don't rely on absolute pixel resolutions (which often screw up your whole design/layout).

For all the other things and tuning you should take a look onto the css media query (e.g. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)):

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your web content isn't being positioned relative to a fixed width parent container, because if it was a scrollbar would load rather than your containers being pushed down. If you want to make the website layout respond to the screen size then you'll need to use a responsive layout.

Here's more info on getting started with responsive design/development:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_responsive_intro.asp

You can also look at using a framework which is really good for learning responsive grid lay outs (and much more). Bootstrap is one of the most popular mobile first responsive frameworks:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could dive in learning few things:

[Relative Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths)

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)